# How to iterate an `std::array` with `std::any` value type?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, stdany

How to iterate an `std::array` with `std::any` value type. Suppose we don't use the `std::tuple` and `std::get` but only a `std::array<std::any, SIZE>`.

I have declared it:

```cpp
std::array<std::any, 5> array_any = {
        "Hello",
        50,
        3.1415926535897l,
        true,
        nullptr
};
```

I could print like this without a loop:

```cpp
std::cout
<< std::boolalpha
<< std::any_cast<const char*>(array_any[0]) << ' '
<< std::any_cast<int>(array_any[1]) << ' '
<< std::any_cast<long double>(array_any[2]) << ' '
<< std::any_cast<bool>(array_any[3]) << ' '
<< std::any_cast<std::nullptr_t>(array_any[4]) << '\n'
<< std::noboolalpha;
```

The output:

```cpp
Hello 50 3.14159 true nullptr
```

How about this?

```
for (const auto& elem : array_any) {
    std::cout << std::any_cast</* placeholder only */>(elem) << ' ';
}
```

How can I achieve this thing to print exactly the same as the first one without the help of `std::tuple` but can use some other vocabulary types such as `std::variant` and also the power of generic programming? Is it possible?

Comment: Don't spam tags. `std::any` didn't exist in C++11.

Comment: The example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type uses a visitor type scheme to print out a vector of std::any